# Difference between tf.keras.backend.one_hot and keras.utils.to_categorical

Tags: python, keras, tensorflow, one-hot-encoding

I'm working on a classification project and need to do one hot encoding on my data set. I'm just wondering what is the difference between `tf.keras.backend.one_hot` and `keras.utils.to_categorical`, and is one of them preferred over the other?

Answer (score 6):

The difference is the input and output.

The `utils.to_categorical` function takes a vector as input and returns a matrix with one hot encoded rows.

The  `backend.one_hot` can be called as a transformation step inbetween a compute sequence of tensors.

It takes nD tensor as input and returns n+1 D one hot encoded tensor.